# What is .funcrc?

Tags: unix, shell

I have not been able to find any information on why this file exists or what should go inside it through the usual channels of investigation.

This is why I am asking here in the hopes of eliciting an answer from someone with the relevant experience.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you have an example of what the file contains or a reference where that file is used?

Comment: I found [this reference](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/bash-elf-command-not-found-741258/): it appears to be a file which adds a number of predefined functions to `bash` on start-up.

Answer (score 1):

I apologise, it looks like `grep .funcrc *` does not look inside hidden files.

On closer inspection it seems that `.bashrc` contains the line `source ~/.funcrc`. I probably should have checked that sooner sorry.

I guess this is some kind of user convention and is not apart of the normal `.bachrc`, `.profile` etc. which is what I was expecting.

I would still be interested in any background how this convention came about if anyone knows.